# Create object list using php

Tags: php, arrays, object

array of items convert into object lists :

```
[ Object {
          id=0,
          label="Myriel",
          group=1
          },
 Object  { 
         id=1,
         label="Napoleon",
         group=1},
         ....
         ....     
         ]
```

create object list using php

Comment: Sounds like another homework question, have you tried something?

Comment: @Epodax there's some students that is so lazy in reading stuffs. LOL. So be good to them. :)

Comment: @Epodax, am try this format,

Comment: Its not very clear what you are actually being asked to do for this homework assignment. Maybe if you gave us the complete question it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
<?php

$Objects = array(
'one' => array(
    'Id' => '0',
    'Label' => 'Myriel',
    'Group' => '1'
    ),

'two' => array(
    'Id' => '1',
    'Label' => 'Napoleon',
    'Group' => '1'        
)

);



$R = json_decode(json_encode($Objects));


echo $R->one->Label; //Would show Myriel
```